# Add new field to node form on validate

Tags: forms, nodes

I am performing a hook_node_validate() and would like to add a new field (e.g. a textfield) during the processing of this function.  Is this possible?  If so could someone let me know how to do it.  I am tried to following so far w/ no luck:

```
function hook_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
    $form['content_type_node_form'] = array(
        '#title'    => t('Phone'),
        '#type'     => 'textfield',
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );      
    form_set_error('time', t('Stop submission to add new field'));
}
```

Thanks, 
Derek

Comment: to understand: does the field already exist in the content type? or are you trying to add a field to the content type while validating a node of that type?

Comment: Hi Geoff.  The field doesn't already exist.  I am trying to add a field to the content type while validating a node of that type. Thanks ~D

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you actually want (from a user story perspective) is if a certain condition is met another, otherwise hidden, field is shown. As @geoff points out that field would need to exist on the content type.

I believe the correct way to do this within the Form API is with the #states parameter in order to conditionally show/hide the phone field. 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states